# Reuse function with return type always equal to the struct that is calling that function in golang

Tags: java, go, reusability, code-reuse

I'm trying to do in Golang something that would be easily done in Java with `Type`. For example:

```java
public class MyClass<Type extends MyClass<Type>> {
    public Type myMethod() {
        // Do something
        return (Type) this;
    }
}


public class Test1 extends MyClass<Test1> {
    public String A;
    
    Test1(String A) {
        this.A = A;
    }
}

public class Test2 extends MyClass<Test2> {
    public String B;

    Test2(String B) {
        this.B = B;
    }
}
```

So, in main I can do

```java
Test1 t1 = new Test1("hello");
Test2 t2 = new Test2("world");
System.out.println(t1.myMethod().A); // Prints "hello"
System.out.println(t2.myMethod().B); // Prints "world"
```

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do somethig similar in Go.
Maybe something like:

```
type test1 struct {
    A string
}

type test2 struct {
    B string
}


func (val Type) MyMethod() Type {
    // Do something
    return val
}


func main() {
    t1 := test1{A: "hello"}
    t2 := test2{B: "world"}
    fmt.Println(t1.MyMethod().A) // Prints "hello"
    fmt.Println(t2.MyMethod().B) // Prints "world"
}
```

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/faq#generic_methods

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [JimB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32880/jimb) I found a way.

From Go 1.18 [Generic Types](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md) are sypported.

So the Java `MyClass` will look something like this in Go:

```golang
type MyGeneric[T any] struct {
    self *T
}

func (val MyGeneric[T]) MyMethod() *T {
    // Do something
    return val.self
}
```

The Java class `Test1` will be:

```golang
type test1 struct {
    MyGeneric[test1]
    A string
}

func MakeTest1(A string) test1 {
    answer := test1{A: A}
    answer.self = &answer
    return answer
}
```

And similarly the Java class `Test2`:

```golang
type test2 struct {
    MyGeneric[test2]
    B string
}

func MakeTest2(B string) test2 {
    answer := test2{B: B}
    answer.self = &answer
    return answer
}
```

So the main is as we wanted

```golang
t1 := MakeTest1("hello")
t2 := MakeTest2("world")
fmt.Println(t1.MyMethod().A) // Prints "hello"
fmt.Println(t2.MyMethod().B) // Prints "world"
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a better strategy than using this `self` variable, but it works.